# ASP.NET Core + Webpack - Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor is not defined when using DllReferencePlugin

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, asp.net-core-2.0, server-side-rendering, dllreferenceplugin

Rendering on the client is absolutely fine, but as soon as I enable SSR I receive the following error: NodeInvocationException: vendor_19f7ef894c06af9bbdef is not defined.

I've put together a sample application which displays this issue for me, it can be found [here](https://github.com/sturatcliffe/Vue2Dotnet2SSR). I've also tried everything in [this](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/717) github issue to no avail. The steps to reproduce are as follows:

Clone the above repo
dotnet restore
npm install
npm run webpack
dotnet run

I've played around with the DllPlugin settings in both webpack.config.js and webpack.config.vendor.js. The only way to get the app working that I've found so far is to remove the following from webpack.config.js:

`new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
  context: __dirname,
  manifest: require("./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json")
})`

Any ideas what I'm missing? I'm sure it's something very simple but I can't figure it out!

I'm running node v8.9.3 / npm v5.6.0 / dotnet v2.1.3 if it helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting because this had no answer for quite long and I had the same error and got it to work at some point. Try the following:

- `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Production"`
- `webpack`
- `dotnet publish -c Release -r YOURRID` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

It worked for me. I really hope it can help you as well.